# Magento table showing size 58 MB while table contain 0 rows

Tags: magento-1.9, database

In my Magento database `catalog_category_product_index_idx` table has no data (0 rows) but it is showing 58.1 MB size.
As shown in below figure :

[image]

Why data showing 32.6 MB? 
Is there any magento logic behind this?

How to decrease its space usage?

Comment: If your mysql db is not set to create separate file for innodb table then all innodb tables data lands in one file. When you remove items from such tables data are removed but the file is not reduced. Space previously taken by the data is now filled with empty space ready to use in the future.

Comment: Hello @Zefiryn, How Do I check "mysql db is not set to create separate file for innodb table" for my database?

Comment: I executed query `Truncate table catalog_category_product_index_idx` but still showing 58 MB space usage. Is `Truncate` not free data from table?

Comment: `show variables like 'innodb_file_per_table';`. You can also check the size of  ibdata1 file in your mysql data folder. If you have this value set to Off then changing it to on does not resolve the issue. All data are still in the ibdata* files. If you want to change it you need to dump all your databases, stop mysql, remove ibdata and ib_log* files, update the configuration (set innodb_file_per_table in my.cnf or ther file that is used on your system for mysql config), start mysql, import dumped databases.

Comment: `show variables like 'innodb_file_per_table';` This setting set to `ON` in mysql. How to release space from empty tables?

Comment: For a quick solution: dump entire database, remove and import from dump